# how to add columns with 5000 length in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I want a table in oracle with 5 columns each of length 5000.
i am using **varchar(5000)** but its not allowing.

```
Error starting at line 8 in command:
ALTER TABLE WORK_STATIC_DATA_AUDIT 
MODIFY ("NEW_VALUE" VARCHAR2(5000))
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype
00910. 00000 -  "specified length too long for its datatype"
*Cause:    for datatypes CHAR and RAW, the length specified was > 2000;
           otherwise, the length specified was > 4000.
*Action:   use a shorter length or switch to a datatype permitting a
           longer length such as a VARCHAR2, LONG CHAR, or LONG RAW
```

i tried **CLOB**, **LONG** but it is saying that we can have only one cloumn of CLOB or Long per table.
Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created and tested table with below DDL:

```
create table x (x clob,z clob,c clob,a clob, y long)
```

Try it and check.

might help...2 columns with long are rejected.

also what you can use as a workaround is that create 5 tables with 1 id column and 1 long column and then make joins with you main table via ID. long way but works

Comment: what is the query that you are using..??

u cannot use like clauses on long data types...

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR2's limit is 4000 CHAR, so you have to use a CLOB for columns of length 4000 or more.  As you pointed out the number of LONG columns per table is 1, but you can have as many as 1000 CLOBs per table (1000 is the *maximum* number of columns for *any* table).

 
5 columns each of length 4000 or more (like 5000) should be achievable with CLOBs.

 
See: [Oracle Datatype Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58242/ch5.htm)